# How to automatically determine IDs for gameObject's?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make ECS (Entity-Component-System) in C++ right now.

Here is my GameObject class :

```
class GameObject
{
private:
    int ID
    /*gameobject name, tranform */
public:
    int GetID();
    
    template<class component>
    void AddComponent()
    {
        component::ComponentAdded(this->ID);
    }

    template<class component>
    component& GetComponent()
    {
        return component(); //todo :: think about how to access
    }

};
```

and here is Meshrenderer(one of my components) :

```
struct MeshRenderer
{
    MeshRenderer();

    static std::vector<Mesh> meshes;
    static std::vector<Material> materials;
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::pair< int , int>> renderables; // gameobjectID, <mesh, material>

    static void ComponentAdded(int gameObjectID);
    static void SetMesh(int gameObjectID, Mesh& mesh);
    static void SetMaterial(int gameObjectID, Material& material);
};
```

I'm trying to fix getcomponent :

```
scene->gameObjects[2]->GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().SetMesh(scene->gameObjects[2]->GetID(), object);
```

to :

```
scene->gameObjects[2]->GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().SetMesh(object);
```

but I don't know how to automatically give gameObject's ID when calling certain components function.

I would appreciate if you give me any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a unique value for each instance of `GameObject` you can:

- introduce a static counter (of instantiations, not of existing instances) to the class `GameObject`
- uincrement it in the constructor of the class `GameObject`
- use its current value, at the time of instaatiating a new object which inherits `GameObject, by assigning it to an instance member of the new object during its constructor

The counter should count instantiations (i.e. not decrement in destructor) instead of existing instances (i.e. do decremetn in destructors). Because I assume that GameObjects might get destroyed and new ones instantiated afterwards. That could end up with newer ones having identical IDs, if older ones get destructed before.

This does of course assume that the number of all instantiations in your program never overflows whatever type you are using. If that happens things get problematic. I hope you do not need that. If you do, I think I might go for a stack of recently deleted IDs, to be used for new instantiations. That however will probably suffer memory issues for the kind of numbers which can overflow a long long int.

(In case the uniqueness suffices as "very likely not to ever be identical" as opposed to "guaranteed to be unique" you can have a look into the concepts of "UUID". You'd have to judge the useability for your purpose yourself.)

Comment: Hello, @Yunnosch, sorry for my bad english skill and explanation about my code. and thank you for your answer. In my code, each gameobject have there unique ID when they are instantiate. If gameobject add certain component, that ID is registered to component and become key of component value, then access that value by getcomponent. What I'm trying to do is  remove first parameter of getcomponent. but I can't find a way to do it. Is there way to access without using parameter?

Comment: Sorry, I am unclear what your problem is. But first of all, please double check that I did not make your post worse by my edit, maybe if I do not get your problem correctly it caused me to create more confusion. I see you already edited, I hope it means that what I did was OK, more or less by accident.

Comment: Could you try for a [mre] demonstrating your problem? E.g. You hard code a UID with a magic value and then ask "How can I use the existing unqiue ID which the GameObject already has instead of this magic number?" I think for that you need to show the code parts which make the ID and generally try for demonstrating your goal/problem in code.

Comment: To clarify, the solution I describe seems to me to be exactly what I also described in my answer. If not please explain the difference. If yes, please explain why it cannot be used for your goal.

Comment: Oh, I think i understand what you are saying now. If what i understand is right, The Component Array part of [link](https://austinmorlan.com/posts/entity_component_system/) is look similar to your answer. Am I understand your answer right?

Comment: No, was unaware of the link. What I mean is that your first comment on this my answer reads llike my answer.

Comment: It is. I just don't get what you're saying yesterday. And based on your answer and the link i think i get what i should know.

Comment: If you describe the core of what you linked (and add the link), you seem to be able to make an interesting answer yourself.

Comment: You mean post my answer right? After finish my code I will, thanks.